# Calling a controller function when the user leaves a webpage - Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, controller

My question is how to execute calling a controller (that in turn takes data from the view to update the db) when the user leaves the webpage?

I tried this code in blade:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            leavingPost();
        };
        function leavingPost()
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: 'attachmentLeaving'
        });
        }
    </script>
```

This in the Route:

```
Route::post('/attachmentLeaving', [TestController::class,'attachmentLeaving']);
```

and something similar to that in the controller:

```
public function attachmentLeaving (Request $request){
        DB::table('users')
            ->where('user_id', $request->id)
            ->update(['item_color' => $request->color]);
        return back()->with('The changes have been saved');
    }
```

When including a function inside window.onbeforeunload (e.g., leavingPost here), the confirmation message that suppose to appear when the user is leaving stop being pop-up and nothing changes in the db.

Can you please help me to figure out what is the problem and how to correct it?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What happens if you call `leavingPost` in your browser console?

Comment: it suppose to be called when leaving the page, so i believe that there is something wrong in the calling that prevent the function (and the confirmation message actually) from being executed. what do you think?

Comment: You might be right. But I think a good way to explore the problem is to isolate the function call from the redirect. If you call the function without redirecting and your record is still not saved, then you have a problem independent from the redirect. If it works when you call it in an isolated manner, then the problem is in the redirect itself. So I would first make sure that the function works without the redirect and when that is assured, make it work with the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a few things to be able to perform an AJAX request back to your route. The 'data' field in the call should be an object mapping each variable to the fields you want from your view. Since you provided little information on what you need to do, look at the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information.

Since we are doing a POST request, we will need a CSRF token, similarly to normal post forms which can be rendered with the`@csrf` blade tag which renders as `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />` in the dom, hence the selector in the `headers` section of the AJAX.

We can then chain on a `success` function to explain what to do when the AJAX call is returned.

```js
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()},
        url: "/attachmentLeaving",
        data: {
           foo: 'bar',
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['foo']) {
                alert("Your Message");
            }
        }
    })
```

If you're looking to do an asynchronous job sequentially, you may need to pursue other avenues. If all you require is to update some data without returning anything back (If the user is leaving the page) then this should be suitable.